# Loading csv.gz from url to bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gzip

I am trying to load all the csv.gz files from [this url](https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/by_year/) to google bigquery. What is the best way to do this?

I tried using pyspark to read the csv.gz files (as I need to perform some data cleaning on these files) but I realized that pyspark doesn't support directly reading files from url. Would it make sense to load the cleaned versions of the csv.gz files into BigQuery or should I dump the raw,original csv.gz files in BigQuery and perform my cleaning process in BigQuery itself?

I was reading the "Google BigQuery: The Definitive Guide" book and it suggests to load the data on Google Cloud Storage. Do I have to load each csv.gz file into Google Cloud Storage or is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would recomend to shell: use `wget` or `curl` to download all files in the url. Then `gsutil cp * gs://yourbucket/folder/`  BigQuery can access these files as external gcs table. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Samuel mentioned, you can use the `curl` command to download the files from the URL and then copy the files to GCS bucket.
If you have heavy transformations to be done on the data I would recommend using Cloud [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs) otherwise you can go for Cloud [Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep) workflow and finally export your clean data to BigQuery table.

Choosing BigQuery for transformations totally depends upon your use-case, data size and budget ie, if you have high volume then direct transformations could be costly.